# Deploying Laravel through phpfog => View [partials.adminHeader] doesn't exist

Tags: deployment, laravel, phpfog

I'm trying to deploy a site on phpfog, all works well except for my backend. I believe that it might have something to do with my restful controllers (public $restful = true;) because the only views that show the error -> (View [partials.adminHeader] doesn't exist) correspond with using restful controllers. Spent several hours trying to troubleshoot this, can't come up with a solution!

//Full Error

Message:

View [partials.adminHeader] doesn't exist.
Location:

/var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/view.php on line 156
Stack Trace:

#0 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/view.php(93): Laravel\View->path('partials.adminH...')
 #1 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/view.php(204): Laravel\View->__construct('partials.adminH...', Array)
 #2 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/helpers.php(526): Laravel\View::make('partials.adminH...', Array)
 #3 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/view.php(359) : eval()'d code(1): view('partials.adminH...')
 #4 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/view.php(359): eval()
 #5 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/blade.php(71): Laravel\View->get()
 #6 [internal function]: Laravel{closure}(Object(Laravel\View))
 #7 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/event.php(199): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
 #8 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/event.php(138): Laravel\Event::fire('laravel.view.en...', Array, true)
 #9 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/view.php(330): Laravel\Event::until('laravel.view.en...', Array)
 #10 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/view.php(408): Laravel\View->render()
 #11 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/view.php(345): Laravel\View->data()
 #12 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/blade.php(71): Laravel\View->get()
 #13 [internal function]: Laravel{closure}(Object(Laravel\View))
 #14 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/event.php(199): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
 #15 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/event.php(138):  Laravel\Event::fire('laravel.view.en...', Array, true)
 #16 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/view.php(330): Laravel\Event::until('laravel.view.en...', Array)
 #17 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/view.php(551): Laravel\View->render()
 #18 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/response.php(246): Laravel\View->__toString()
 #19 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/laravel/laravel.php(178): Laravel\Response->render()
 #20 /var/fog/apps/app58421/shipwatch.phpfogapp.com/public/index.php(34): require('/var/fog/apps/a...')
 #21 {main}

Comment: What version of PHP is phpfog running? It seems not to be able to construct your objects.

Comment: 5.3.2...if i change my public function get_index() to public function action_index() it displays a 404 error, so at least that's something different.

Comment: reading online that laravel may not be deployable to a free hosting site such as non-paid version of phpfog...can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, chmod your storage folder as well. chmod -R 755

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you directly render some content in the get() methods

like

```
class DemoPage_Controller
{
    public function getPosts()
    {
         echo 'Direct outputting';
         return;

         //return View::make('demopagetemplate');
    }
}
```

If the above still dosent work, make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled on Apache (you can use phpinfo() to chk this)